# useFakeTimers and async callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

Consider this function

```
function startTimerWithAsyncCallback(
    firstAsyncFunction,
    secondAsyncFunction,
    thirdAsyncFunction,
    millis,
) {
    setTimeout(async () => {
        await firstAsyncFunction();
        await secondAsyncFunction();
        await thirdAsyncFunction();
    }, millis);
}
```

I want to test that the 3 async functions are called after timeout, using jest fake timers.

```
test('fake timers', () => {
    jest.useFakeTimers();

    const firstAsyncFunction = jest.fn();
    const secondAsyncFunction = jest.fn();
    const thirdAsyncFunction = jest.fn();

    startTimerWithAsyncCallback(
        firstAsyncFunction,
        secondAsyncFunction,
        thirdAsyncFunction,
        1000,
    );
    jest.advanceTimersByTime(2000);

    expect(firstAsyncFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(secondAsyncFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();  // FAILS HERE !
    expect(thirdAsyncFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

With this test, first async function is pending and next async functions are not called. I did not find a way to tell: "wait that the setTimeout's callback is finished" before doing assertions

I came up with a workaround which is to restore real timers and wait 0 millisecond before asserting.

```
test('fake timers and restore real timers', async () => {
    jest.useFakeTimers();

    const firstAsyncFunction = jest.fn();
    const secondAsyncFunction = jest.fn();
    const thirdAsyncFunction = jest.fn();

    startTimerWithAsyncCallback(
        firstAsyncFunction,
        secondAsyncFunction,
        thirdAsyncFunction,
        1000,
    );
    jest.advanceTimersByTime(2000);

    expect(firstAsyncFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
    await waitAsyncFunctionsToComplete();             // WORKAROUND
    expect(secondAsyncFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(thirdAsyncFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
});

async function waitAsyncFunctionsToComplete() {
    jest.useRealTimers();
    await delay(0);
    jest.useFakeTimers();
}

async function delay(ms) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(resolve, ms);
    });
}
```

Is there a more proper way to achieve this ?

Comment: The reason this is inconvenient to test is that `startTimerWithAsyncCallback()` offers no way to know when it has finished. It would be cleaner if this function returned a promise you could use to know when it’s complete.

Comment: @MarkMeyer I get your point. However, in my initial problem, I use `setInterval` rather than `setTimeout` to periodically run the asyncCallback. Maybe I should reconsider my design...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by Mark Meyer in comments, making `startTimerWithAsyncCallback` returning a Promise is more convenient for testing

```
function startTimerWithAsyncCallback(
    firstAsyncFunction,
    secondAsyncFunction,
    thirdAsyncFunction,
    millis,
) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {      // <==
        setTimeout(async () => {
            await firstAsyncFunction();
            await secondAsyncFunction();
            await thirdAsyncFunction();
            resolve();                     // <==
        }, millis);
    });
}


describe('Using async callbacks with timers', () => {
    test('fake timers', async () => {
        jest.useFakeTimers();

        const firstAsyncFunction = jest.fn();
        const secondAsyncFunction = jest.fn();
        const thirdAsyncFunction = jest.fn();

        const promise = startTimerWithAsyncCallback( // <==
            firstAsyncFunction,
            secondAsyncFunction,
            thirdAsyncFunction,
            1000,
        );
        jest.advanceTimersByTime(2000);

        await promise;  <==

        expect(firstAsyncFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(secondAsyncFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(thirdAsyncFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simply just use `@sinonjs/fake-timers` instead of `jest.useFakeTimers()`.

Kinda looks like they just gave up on the whole thing.

> If you pass ‘modern’ as an argument, @sinonjs/fake-timers will be used
> as implementation instead of Jest’s own fake timers. This also mocks
> additional timers like Date. ‘modern’ will be the default behavior in
> Jest 27.
> https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#mock-timers