# useFakeTimers("modern") and async callback tests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs

[useFakeTimers and async callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54256154/usefaketimers-and-async-callback) talks about legacy timers but I am trying to do it with `modern` timers.

I have the jest configuration for `react-native`

```
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "modulePathIgnorePatterns": [
      "<rootDir>/example/node_modules",
      "<rootDir>/lib/"
    ]
  },
```

And I this is my test file.  And places where I tried putting in `jest.useFakeTimers("modern");` (jest 26) or `jest.useFakeTimers();` (jest 29)

```
describe("http", () => {
    beforeAll(() => {
        //jest.useFakeTimers("modern");
    })
    beforeEach(() => {
        //jest.useFakeTimers("modern");
    })

    it("This does not work", async () => {
        //jest.useFakeTimers("modern");

    })

    it("This also does not work", () => {

        return Promise.resolve("foo");

    })

    it("This works", () => {
        //jest.useFakeTimers("modern");

    })

    afterEach(() => {
        // jest.useRealTimers();
    })
})
```

The moment I enable it on one the `async` test yields

> Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000 ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000 ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.

I am using Jest 26.6.3 which is the one used in Expo SDK 47 at the moment. I also tried to upgrade to `jest@29.3.1` and still see the same failure.  Just in case I also created [a bug](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/13678)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like to get this to work and assuming you don't really care about the precise clock time the timer needs to be configured as:

```
jest.useFakeTimers({ advanceTimers: true });
```

However, time still increments.  So this

```
describe("http", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.useFakeTimers({ advanceTimers: true });
  })

  it("This does not work", async () => {
    jest.setSystemTime(new Date("2022-01-01T00:00:00Z"));
    await fetch("https://trajano.net");
    console.log(new Date());
  })

  afterEach(() => {
    jest.useRealTimers();
  })
})
```

will not yield `2022-01-01T00:00:00.000Z` to the console but may be `2022-01-01T00:00:00.080Z`